# How to persist oneToOne relation when saving secondary Entity

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence, one-to-one

I'm using SPRING DATA JPA and I have following entities:

```
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SOME_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SOME_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "SOME_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityBField", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private EntityB entityB;
}
    
    
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SOME_OTHER_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SOME_OTHER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "SOME_OTHER_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    private Integer type;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityaId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private EntityA entityBField;
}
```

This is the tables definition:

```
create table EntityA(
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(255)
);
create table EntityB(
  id int primary key,
  type int,
  entitya_Id int  FOREIGN KEY ("entitya_Id")
      REFERENCES "EntityA" ("id")
);
```

I create and save one instance as follow:

```
    EntityA a = new EntityA();
    EntityB b = new EntityB();
    a.setEntityB(b);
    entityARepository.save(a)
```

What happens is that both entityA and entityB are persisted, but the foreign key entityaId on EntityB is null.
Could you suggest how should I persist the foreign key linking EntityB to EntityA?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement method EntityA.setEntityB like this:

```
public class EntityA {

    public void setEntityB(EntityB entityB) {
        if (entityB == null) {
            if (this.entityB != null) {
                this.entityB.setEntityBField(null);
            }
        }
        else {
            entityB.setEntityBField(this);
        }
        this.entityB = entityB;
    }

}
```

EntityB.setEntityBField should be usual setter:

```
public class EntityB {

  public void setEntityBField(EntityA entityBField) {
    this.entityBField = entityBField;
  }

}
```

Also, you might need "optional = false" in the annotation:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityBField", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
private EntityB entityB;
```

See the example in this article:
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

**Note:**

`mappedBy = "entityBField"` means that

`EntityB.entityBField` is responsible for managing one-to-one relationship,

so when you create `EntityB b = new EntityB()` and set `a.setEntityB(b)`, then `b.entityBField` is null when you do cascading save: `entityARepository.save(a)`

This is why `b.entityBField` (foreign key "entitya_Id") is null in the database.

By implementing correct setter in EntityA, you help JPA understand, that `entityB.entityBField` should be set to the primary key of EntityA (`entityB.setEntityBField(this)`)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be like this:

```
EntityA a = new EntityA();
EntityB b = new EntityB();
b.setEntityBField(a);
entityARepository.save(a)
```

The only change you need to make is the following line:

```
b.setEntityBField(a);
```